# Rendering Partial View: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, partial-views, strongly-typed-view

To give some background on the entities, I have a Course entity and a Module entity, with a one to many relationship. This means that a course can have many modules.

I wanted to be able to add as many modules dynamically so I went with the direction of adding partial views to the edit page of course.

2 views are concerned here:

1. Modules - a strongly typed view within the course controller that is
   just an edit page displaying all modules related to a course
2. _Add - a strongly typed partial view within the module controller that is a create page for modules

In the view Modules, I add this line to test if the partial renders:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add")
```

However, I always get this error: **The name 'model' does not exist in the current context**

I tried passing a model from reading other sources with the following below:

1. `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add", Model)`
2. `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add", model)`
3. `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add", new RocketLabs.Models.Module())`

But none of them work. Any ideas? Any piece of advice or comment would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE 2 - FULL CODES**

Modules View (Parent) code:

```
@model RocketLabs.Models.Course

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Modules";
}

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="row-fluid">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Course Modules</legend>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => model.Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Description)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Author)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreateDate)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IndustryId)                    
                </div>
                <div class="span4 pull-right">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium" value="Save Course" />
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Course")" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-medium">Back to Courses</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-medium"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Module</a>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">                        
                        @*@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Module/_Add", Model); }*@
                        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add", Model)*@
                        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add", model)*@
                        @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Module/_Add", new RocketLabs.Models.Module())*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

_Add Partial Page code:

```
@model RocketLabs.Models.Module

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Module</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        ...
```

Could it be the conflict between the @model in the child partial and the @model in the parent view?

Comment: Please post the code of your `_Add` partial!

Comment: Appreciate your reply! Updated it :)

Comment: You get this error when the code generated by ASP.NET by the Razor view engine contains the identifier `model` which is not defined in the code. There is nothing in the snippets you have posted here that makes it obvious where the mistake is. However, the name of the model property in the view is `Model` with capital M so perhaps you need to find where you are referring to this property using wrong capitalization. The error message you get from ASP.NET should help you pinpoint where the error is.

Comment: The error would have some more information, ie. Line Number and File where it breaks. Could you check and see where exactly it is breaking?

Comment: Ok, let me put the entire code of both views. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: You still haven't posted your full `_Add` partial...

Answer (score 1):

This line is probably causing problems:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => model.Id)
```

You should replace `Model` with `model`.

Troubleshooting this kind of spelling mistake isn't hard. If you have turned on detailed error messages in ASP.NET something like this will be displayed in your browser:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 20:                 </div>
Line 21:                 <div class="span4">
Line 22:                     @Html.HiddenFor(Model => model.Id)
Line 23:                     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

Source File: ...\MyView.cshtml    Line: 22 

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:
```

The offending line (line 22) is highlighted in red making it quite obvious where the error is.

If you have a really bad syntax error then the code displayed below the heading *Source Error* may be hard to understand. In that case you can click on the text *Show Complete Compilation Source* to see what the compiler is having a hard time to understand and hopefully be able to correlate that back to your Razer view engine source code.

Comment: If you see in **Modules View (Parent) code**, I tried different ways including Model with a capital M. Still didn't work for me though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty outdated but still. I was clever enough to name my mvc project *WebClient* which conflicts with *System.Net.WebClient* namespace.

So razor searched for class and found one, unfortunately in system dll.

So don't be like me and choose name of project wisely, or just prefix your class with full path.